# Is the sentence '意思にしか動くな' a correct sentence?

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-japanese

Is the sentence '意思にしか動くな' a correct sentence? I mean to say someting in the lines of 'Act on (move by) will alone'.

is it's meaning clear and are there more elaborate ways of conveing that meaning in japanese?

Answer (score 2):

意思にしか動くな is ungrammatical, mainly because of に. ～**に**動く means "to move **to** ～", as in 南に動く ("to move to the south"). Here, the correct particle you have to use is **で**.

- (～の)意思で動く: to act on ～'s will, to act with a purpose
- 自分の意思で動く: to act on your own volition

Then you can combine it with しか and say something like this:

- ～の意思でしか動かない: to act only on ～'s will
- 自分の意思でしか動くな: Act only on your own volition!